# youtube api is bound to window instead of inside sandbox iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, sandbox

I am trying to wrap the youtube api inside of a sandboxed iframe and giving it only the required permissions.

I am using the react-frame-component package to wrap a youtube player component in a sandboxed iframe. I have debugged it to the point where I know why the video is not showing up, but can't figure out why it's happening.

When it gets to the point for the youtube-api to replace the original html element with the youtube iframe, the youtube api can't find the specified element because it is inside of a sandboxed iframe. The code below is some of the youtube code that gets fetched and executed. I have placed a comment explaining what what I changed for the youtube code to work, but the issue is that the youtube api isn't running in the context of the sandboxed iframe.

```
function W(a, b, c) {
    this.h = this.a = this.b = null;
    this.g = this[r] || (this[r] = ++t);
    this.c = 0;
    this.A = !1;
    this.s = [];
    this.f = null;
    this.l = c;
    this.m = {};
    c = document;

    // Here, the document is not the document of the iframe, but the
    // document of the entire page. I need this to be something like
    // window.frames["myIframe"].contentDocument.getElementById(a)

    if (a = l(a) ? c.getElementById(a) : a)
        if (c = "iframe" == a.tagName.toLowerCase(),
        b.host || (b.host = c ? Ba(a.src) : "https://www.youtube.com"),
        this.b = new Wa(b),
        c || (b = Ya(this, a),
        this.h = a,
        (c = a.parentNode) && c.replaceChild(b, a),
        a = b),
        this.a = a,
        this.a.id || (a = b = this.a,
        a = a[r] || (a[r] = ++t),
        b.id = "widget" + a),
        R[this.a.id] = this,
        window.postMessage) {
            this.f = new M;
            Za(this);
            b = V(this.b, "events");
            for (var d in b)
                b.hasOwnProperty(d) && this.addEventListener(d, b[d]);
            for (var e in Sa)
                $a(this, e)
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this code that you wrote? Or is this something provided to you by youtube?

Comment: @ZachM. This is something that is provided by youtube. Behind the scenes, youtube is making a network request to https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api, which then in turn makes a network request to https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflxGrywa/www-widgetapi.js, which is where this code is from.

Comment: Have you tried this code format? `<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{VIDEOID}?rel=0&html5=1" width="480" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>`.

Comment: @jess This works yeah, but if I do it this way, I lose the functionality to control the onError callback, which is required for my application.